# Is it possible to set (in the application code) the font used for title bar text of a Winform?

Tags: winforms

Can the font used for a Winforms title bar text be changed in the application code?

The default font for the Winforms title bar text is almost illegible with certain combinations of letters.  `TJ`, for example, can be mistaken for a D. When displaying *arbitrary* letter-combinations  in that location, product codes, say, or something else that is not a word, it's easy for users to make mistakes when reading what is there.

Comment: It is an OS setting and affects the title bar of every app that runs on the user's desktop.  In other words, if the user is likely to mis-read the title of your app then they are just as likely to do so with every other app as well.  And they'll change the preference with the OS-provided widget, implementing it yourself is not sensible.

Comment: Thanks. The main problem is with non-words, like product codes, as there are no lexical guard-rails for the reader in that case. Most of the time what is shown there is legible enough.

Comment: I don't understand the close vote. What is wrong with a Yes/No question whose answer is "no"?

Comment: It's not impossible, it's probably not worth the effort (to make the change and maintain the app: multiple factor have to be considered, as changes in the User preference, screen scaling, high-dpi, multiple System and System updates, etc.). You can use DWM Composition to change the appearance of a Window's Caption. Or draw a custom Caption entirely, using DWM to move the non-client area into the client area. -- Maybe you just need to add a band under the default Caption that shows relevant information about the content of that Window, including your *code*, using a different / larger Font.

Comment: Or, see [Fancy Windows Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33716/fancy-windows-forms) or a *skinner* as [MaterialSkin](https://github.com/leocb/MaterialSkin)